# Disable code autoformatting in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

Does anyone know of a way to *completely* disable any form of automatic formatting or indentation in the current version of Xcode? Essentially, as far as text editing, I want it to behave like a "dumb" editor, e.g. TextEdit or Notepad.

Comment: I am thinking about removing everything from your question apart the last paragraph since it's just useless noise and it doesn't have anything to do with the actual question.

Comment: Anyway, most likely Xcode is not the correct tool for you, it's not really configurable. However, as far as I know, Xcode behaves as dumb editor for every file it does not recognize. Therefore changing the file extension could do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know off-hand of any environment for the Mac that has similar functionality to XCode (or even better, MSVS), but with a fully configurable editor?

Comment: Any of the Idea versions (e.g. IntelliJ, Appcode, Webstorm) would be probably good enough for you as a simple editor. For example "Android Studio" version of Idea is free to download and there is also a Fortran plugin you could install.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try that.

Comment: Have you tried changing Xcode's settings on the Text Editing tab of the preferences dialog?

Comment: Ken, I tried disabling anything on that tab that looked even vaguely relevant, to no effect. I can confirm, though, that change the extension does remove the autoformatting. It does lose a lot of the other functionality as well, though.